# Get data from some years back in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a table in MySQL in which I keep the dates that the customer booked for the first time. I want to get all the customers that they booked 1 year back from that date.

The date is displayed like this:

[image]

How can I select the customers from 1 year back? I have seen multiple answers with `DATEADD` method like:

```
SELECT Kunde FROM `Buchungen` WHERE Buchungsdatum > date_add(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())
```

but it gives me this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '-1, GETDATE()) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

If I do:

```
SELECT Kunde FROM `Buchungen` WHERE Buchungsdatum > DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())
```

then I get this:

> 1305 - FUNCTION db034.DATEADD does not exist

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Dose This Work "SELECT Kunde FROM `Buchungen` WHERE Buchungsdatum between '2014-01-01' and '2015-01-01' " 
You can set 2 dates difference for 1 year back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATE_ADD(GETDATE(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)
```

or

```
DATE_SUB(GETDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

The [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)